# Why can't I get value_type from iterator_traits?

Tags: c++, types, iterator, typename, iterator-traits

I'm doing this:

```
const int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
const auto foo = cbegin(arr);
const typename iterator_traits<decltype(foo)>::value_type bar = 1;
```

I would have expected `bar` to have the type `int`. But instead I'm getting an error:

> error C2039: `value_type`: is not a member of `std::iterator_traits<_Ty *const >`

Is this a problem with the `const` do I need to strip that or something?

Comment: I generally use [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) for this. Though, I'm reluctant to post this as an answer because I'm not entirely comfortable with why it seems to fix all of these problems. So it might not be the right solution. You would write `const typename std::iterator_traits<std::decay_t<decltype(foo)>>::value_type bar = 1;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, I was hoping I could make this work for either a `vector` or an array... `decay` *would* still work there though... so maybe that's best?

Comment: @JonathanMee It does work for non-pointer iterator types as well. In my experience it fixes this kind of problem every time and magically works. Though again, the fact that it seems like magic to me leaves me nervous about recommending it.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox That change is intended to deal with `volatile T*`. It does not add a specialization for `T* const`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed the `const` is problematic, you do basically:

```
std::iterator_traits<const int* const>::value_type // incorrect due to the last const
```

You might fix it by changing it to

```
std::iterator_traits<const int*>::value_type // Correct
```

You might use `std::decay` or `std::remove_cv` for that:

```
const typename std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cv_t<decltype(foo)>>::value_type
```

(or drop `const` from `foo` if relevant).

Comment: It's worth pointing out [@FantasticMrFox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113330/why-cant-i-get-value-type-from-iterator-traits/54114989#comment95059225_54113330) that the `remove_cv_t` happens automatically in C++20. So I'd say this is indeed the preferred solution.

Answer (score 19):

The issue here is with the line

```
const auto foo = cbegin(arr);
```

`cbegin(arr)` is going to return a `int const *` (pointer to const int) so applying `const` to that with `const auto foo` means `foo` is a `int const * const` (const pointer to const int)

`std::iterator_traits` is only specialized for a `T*` or `T const*` so giving it a `T* const` fails since there is no valid specialization.

You can fix this by removing the constness in the declaration of `bar` with

```
const typename std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cv_t<decltype(foo)>>::value_type
```

or you can change `foo` to

```
auto foo = std::cbegin(arr);
```

if you are okay with it not being `const`.

Comment: It “fixes” the problem by weakening the type contract of `foo`. This is hardly a good solution: `foo` *should* be declared `const`. Don’t remove that!

Comment: I agree with @KonradRudolph that it would be best to leave `foo` as `const`. I feel like it would be better to instead fix the template argument given to `iterator_traits`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've updated the answer but it really depends on what the OP wants to do with it.  You can normally reassign `const_iterators` from containers so removing the `const` makes it behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a const qualified iterator `const auto foo = cbegin(arr);` is questionable. What use do you have for an iterator on which you cannot apply `operator++()`? Also, the **Iterator** requirement requires the type `int const *const` to be **Copy Assignable**; as such, the variable `foo` does not satisfy the **Iterator** requirement. So strictly speaking, `foo` is not an **Iterator**.

Comment: I mean `next` still works on it fine? It's the same argument against `const char* const` but in some cases this compiles into more optimized code than a `const char*`

Comment: @JonathanMee `std::next` requires an argument that satisfy [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), which requires the type to be CopyAssignable through the LegacyIterator requirement. An Iterator type is intrinsically not const qualifiable.

Comment: @JulienVillrmure-Fréchette I assume from your statement: "An Iterator type is intrinsically not const qualifiable." That you mean that the only way to modify a constant iterator would be to operate on a copy of it? And that generally the point of an iterator is modification?

Comment: Trivial example to a meaningful iterator constant: the end of a range. Though I also don't see a use-case for const cbegin...